# Looking for a solution to retrieve either 1 or max of the value from a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Table A 
Owner   row_no   category
A        1         U
B        1         T
B        2         T
C        1         U
C        2         T
C        3         U
C        4         U
```

I'm looking for a solution that stores values into other table which should retrieve

1. row_no as 1 if the value is 1 and should return max(row_no)-1 if
   the value isn't 1.
2. category should be either T or U or both based on whether an owner
   has opted for only T or U or both in TABLE A.

Resultant table should be something like below.

```
Table B 
Owner   row_no   category
A        1         U
B        1         T
C        3        Both
```

I tried using the below approach which turns out to be an error.

```
SELECT * INTO B FROM A
WHERE 
ROW_NO LIKE CASE
WHEN ROW_NO=1 then ROW_NO
ELSE max(ROW_NO)-1
END
```

Haven't figured out yet on retrieving the category!

Could you please help with right approach ?!

*NEW EDIT*

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do like this:

```
declare @table table (owner nvarchar(50),row_no int)

insert into @table

values

('A',       1),
('B',       1),
('B',       2),
('C',       1),
('C',       2),
('C',       3),
('C',       4)

select owner,row_no from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by owner order by la desc) as rn from (
select *,LEAD(row_no,1,1) over(partition by owner order by row_no) as la from @table
)X 
)z where rn = 1
```

**EDIT UPDATE**

With categoryList you can do like this

```
declare @table table (owner nvarchar(50),row_no int,category nvarchar(50))

insert into @table

values

('A',       1,'U'),
('B',       1,'T'),
('B',       2,'T'),
('C',       1,'U'),
('C',       2,'T'),
('C',       3,'U'),
('C',       4,'U')

;
with category as (
select owner,  categoryList = stuff((select  N', ' + Category
from (Select distinct owner,category from  @table t2
) z
where z.owner  = t1.owner 
FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
from @table t1
group by owner 
)


select z.owner,row_no,y.categoryList from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by owner order by la desc) as rn from (
select *,LEAD(row_no,1,1) over(partition by owner order by row_no) as la from @table
)X 
)z 
inner join category y on z.owner = y.owner
where rn = 1
```

[DBFiddeldemo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=392d0ed058010791d165a2f6a0e73c86)

Comment: I  believe you wanted `LEAD(row_no,1,1) over(partition by owner order by row_no)` instead of `LEAD(row_no,1,1) over(partition by owner order by owner)`. Partitioning and ordering by the same table won't give you stable results.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Yes of cause - My bad :) Even though it gives the same result. But yes Row_no is the right one to sort by

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please also assist on new edit ?!

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it throws an error at 'with category as' statement with a red underline. Unable to execute.

Comment: Works fine here

Comment: @PradeepVaranasi Remember the semicolon see my update with demo

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT *, MAX(row_no)OVER(PARTITION BY owner) AS m
  FROM tab
)
SELECT owner, row_no
INTO tab2
FROM cte
WHERE row_no = m-1 OR m=1;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=22726f384865ece4c44a31a18cbd4093)**

*Warning! I've made an assumption that values in row_no are consecutive.*

---

Without cte/subquery:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *
INTO tabB
FROM tab
ORDER BY IIF(MAX(row_no)OVER(PARTITION BY owner) IN (row_no+1,1),0,1)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e5dcb6110f7bdc805d0fc9b5ef52b8a)**

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please also assist on new edit ?!